# Dynamic type of arraylist and custom adapter

Tags: android, android-adapter, custom-adapter

I have similar 5 class. Each class "Code" , "Name" property. I use custom adapter for list them and I want to use 1 adapter for all. Is this possible ?

I jam in there : holder.txtCode.setText(list.get(position).getCode() ????);
                 holder.txtName.setText(list.get(position).getName() ?????);

```
public class AdapterCodeName extends BaseAdapter {
    private static ArrayList<?> list;
    private static ArrayList<?> listOrj;
    private static ArrayList<?> mOriginalValues;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    public AdapterCodeName (Context context, ArrayList<?> results){
        list = results;
        listOrj = results;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return list.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_code_name, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtCode = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtCode);
            holder.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        holder.txtCode.setText(list.get(position).getCode() ????);
        holder.txtName.setText(list.get(position).getName() ?????);

        return convertView;
    }
    static class ViewHolder{
        TextView txtCode,txtName;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

extend all classes from one class (interface), and create adapter with list of objects of base type/interface:

```
public interface Item {
    String getName();
    String getCode();
}


public class ListItem1 implements Item {
    private String name;
    private String code;

    @Override
    public getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public getCode() {
        return code;
    }
}

public class ListItem2 implements Item {
    private String name;
    private String code;
    private String somethingElse;

    @Override
    public getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public getCode() {
        return code;
    }
}
```

in Adapter:

```
private static ArrayList<? extends Item> list;

@Override
public Item getItem(int i) {
    return list.get(i);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ...

    holder.txtCode.setText(list.get(position).getCode());
    holder.txtName.setText(list.get(position).getName());

    return convertView;
}
```